# Why cannot create migrations on flask?

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate, flask-script

Pycharm2018.1.4 
Unable to create migrations with the execution of python manage.py db init

Comment: You need to provide more details, impossible to troubleshoot your problem as described.

Comment: Thank you so much. I found the reason now,one function is not right and I should pip install pymysql!